# Select elements that don't have any classes containing a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I would like a jQuery selector that selects any elements that do not have a class containing the string '-text';

For example in the following:

```
<img class="cow" > 
<img class="monkey" > 
<img class="cow-text" > 
<img class="monkey-text" >
```

I would like to select:

```
<img class="cow" > 
<img class="monkey" >
```

I know I need to use `not`, but I'm unsure of the format. The following results in no items being selected:

`$('.panel').find('.layer').not('[class*="-text"]');`

Comment: It's probably what `panel` is, not what selectors/chains you're using.

Comment: There'd be less assumptions/inferences/guesswork if you include in your markup whatever has the class of `panel`, per your updated selector.

Comment: NB: You should consider using a different schema for the class names to make this easier. (And please don't say you can't change the HTML...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class always ends with "*-text"* you should use the [EndsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector e.g.

```
panel.find('img').not('[class$="-text"]');
```

Or

```
panel.find('img:not([class$="-text"])')
```

This is a more precise solution, the wildcard selector means classes like `some-text-class` or `-text-class` would also be picked up by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
panel.find('img').not('[class*="-text"]');
```

Comment: Sorry. Stupid typo. That isn't the problem.

Comment: @Pedr also make sure the `panel` is referring the correct element

Comment: Will this work if there are multiple classes defined for the element?

Answer (score 0):

Try find all img elements and remove all, that end with `-text`. And use each for multiple elements.
e.g. class="monkey-text"

```
$("img").not("[class$='-text']").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Second preview shows the string `text-` at the begin of the string. Just replace `$` to at `^`
e.g. class="text-monkey"

```
$("img").not("[class^='text-']").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```